# Does anybody know the part number of this tile?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, part-database

Does anybody know the part number of this tile? The size is 2x14. 
It has an unusual height. It's higher than 1 plate, lower than 2, so it's an exact 1/2 of a brick. See the given picture for the bottom:

[image: top]

[image: bottom]

Comment: Are sure this is not 2 plates high? Could you take another picture with plates side by side?

Comment: Hi user15123.  Welcome to Bricks.StackExchange.  If Alex's answer is what you were looking for it'd be nice to click the checkbox by the answer to accept it.  https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 8):

That's [Train Level Crossing Center Rail Cap Insert 2 x 14 x 2/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=812). Although as naming suggests it is 2/3 of a brick, so it must be two plates high.

Picture from Bricklink:

[image]

And here is a [list](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=812&colorID=9&in=A) of 6 sets it was part of.